# Puppet: Exec from class when Exec from another class is successful

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I want to call an Exec only when another Exec from a different class is executed successfully.

```
class mysql {
    exec { 'load-sql':
        command => 'mysql -uadmi -pxxx general < /vagrant/sites/ddbb/general.sql',
        path    => ['/bin', '/usr/bin'],
        timeout => 0,
        onlyif   => "test -f /vagrant/sites/ddbb/general.sql",
    }
    exec { 'delete-general-sql':
        command => 'sudo rm /vagrant/sites/ddbb/general.sql',
        path    => ['/bin', '/usr/bin'],
        onlyif   => "test -f /vagrant/sites/ddbb/general.sql",
        require => Exec['load-sql'],
    }
}

class sphinx {
    exec { 'sphinx-create-all-index':
        command => 'sudo indexer -c /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf --all --rotate',
        require => Exec['load-sql'],
        path => '/usr/bin/';
    }
}
```

The command 'delete-general-sql' is executed only if 'load-sql' is executed successfully but 'sphinx-create-all-index'ignores the result of 'load-sql'...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You mess up with `require` and `onlyif`. 
Read about [puppet ordering](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html).

> **require**
>
> Causes a resource to be applied after the target resource.

so

```
require => Exec['load-sql'],
```

means, execute resource after execution of `exec{'load-sql':}` resource.

On the other hand `onlyif` in [`exec`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec) means:

> If this parameter is set, then this exec will only run if the command has an exit code of 0.

So you must add `onlyif` with proper test (probably `onlyif   => "test -f /vagrant/sites/ddbb/general.sql`) to `'sphinx-create-all-index'`.

Answer (score 0):

To make the dependent `exec` run *only* once the previous one did run, you can use `subscribe` and `refreshonly`.

```
exec { 'sphinx-create-all-index':
    command => 'sudo indexer -c /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf --all --rotate',
    subscribe => Exec['load-sql'],
    refreshonly => true,
    path => '/usr/bin/';
}
```

This has some caveats - you may have a hard time to get Puppet to execute this task again if something goes wrong the first time around.